# Difference between local -a args=( ) and local args=( )

Tags: bash, shell-script

Is there a differece between:

```
local args=("$@")
```

and

```
local -a args=("$@")
```

I see some code with the `-a` argument, but cannot figure out what it's there for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. Assigning an array directly already forces it to be an array. You would only need to use `-a` if you were not assigning and wanted the variable to start with `()`.

Comment: right, yeah, the title of the question is different than the body for a reason... you have answered my question though, do you know if this `local -a args=()` is different than `local -a args=( )` (the extra space between the parens)

Comment: `$ foo=( )`
`$ echo ${#foo[@]}`
`0`
No difference.

Comment: No, there is no difference between `local -a args=()` and `local -a args=( )`

Comment: To complement this answer, an expression like this one `local -a args` would only declare the creation of a variable of type array in the local scope (usually a function). It is a declaration of intent only. In the case of `local -a args=()` there is an assignment in addition to the declaration of the variable. The explicit type declaration via the `-a` switch can be bypassed if there is declaration and assignment all-in-one as in `local args=()`